# how to check for blank in case of choice field in Getitems in filter query in power automate?

Tags: power-automate

I tried below, this is working fine if I put some choice value but in case of blank it is not fetching data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correct filter query should be:

columnName eq null

Make sure that if you are using another query to use ()
eg

(columnName eq null) and (columnName eq '1')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).